# how to convert byte array to zip file in SPring boot

Tags: java, excel, spring, zip

I need to convert array byte to zip file. but my out put is a empty zip file. I don't understand that.

I get help from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javazip/javazip_zipoutputstream_write.htm)

my code is:

```
String resultBase64  = reportApplicationService.fetchReportExcel(...);

if (resultBase64 != null) {
    
    byte[] excel = base64.decode( resultBase64 );
    
    ZipInputStream z = new ZipInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(excel));
    int length;
    while ((length = z.read(excel)) > 0) {
        zip.write(excel, 0, length);
    }

    zip.closeEntry();
    zip.finish();
    z.close();

    zip.close();
    outputStream.flush();
    
    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.zip");
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setContentLength((int) outputStream.size());
    StreamUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()), response.getOutputStream());
    
}
```

the `z.read(excel)` is -1

thanks

Comment: So the String `result` is a base64 encoded zip file? In that case you'll need to call `z.getNextEntry()` before you try to read from it.

Comment: hello, no, result is a base64 encoded file (byte array). I need to convert the file (byte array) to a zip file.

Comment: If you aren't reading zipped data, don't use `ZipInputStream`.

Comment: Just use your existing `ByteArrayInputStream` without wrapping it.

Comment: And perhaps you shouldn't read its contents into the same byte array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it in [here](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/java/byte+array+to+zip+java) . I changed my code :

```
result = reportApplicationService.fetchReportExcel(id, periodId, compareId1, compareId2, branches);

if (result != null) {

    byte[] excel = base64.decode( result );

    ZipEntry entry = new ZipEntry("z.xls");
    entry.setSize(excel.length);
    zip.putNextEntry(entry);
    zip.write(excel);
    zip.closeEntry();

    zip.close();
    outputStream.flush();

    response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.zip");
    response.setContentType("application/zip");
    response.setContentLength((int) outputStream.size());
    StreamUtils.copy(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray()), response.getOutputStream());

}
```

create a file with `z.xls` name into `name.zip`.